# Replace double quotes with single quote in a JSON string

Tags: apex, string

We have JSON sent to us by webservice which has double quotes in value part (Key => Value)in the JSON String. Below is how the JSON looks like

```
[{
        "dp_id": "SDN071076",
        "list1": "Specially Designated Nationals and Blocked Persons [OFAC]",
        "type": "CYBER2",
        "category": "Entity",
        "name": "ITSEC TEAM AKA AMN PARDAZESH KHARAZMI AKA \"IT SECURITY & PENETRATION TESTING TEAM\" AKA IT SECURITY AND PENETRATION TESTING TEAM AKA \"POOYA DIGITAL SECURITY GROUP\"",
        "street1": "Unit 2, No. 129, Mir Ali Akbari St, Motahari Avenue",
        "street2": "",
        "city": "Tehran",
        "state": "",
        "country": "Iran (Islamic Republic of)",
        "ctrycode": "IR",
        "notes": "Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions . [CYBER2].<BR>",
        "frc": "",
        "startdate": "9/14/2017",
        "enddate": "12/30/2099",
        "frserve": "",
        "optionalid": "a011H00000VI7x8QAD",
        "alerttype": "_Y"
    }]
```

If you look at the ***name*** key in the JSON it has double quotes in the value, so we normally to deserialize to a inner class type Apex throws us below error:

> Unexpected character ('I' (code 73)): was expecting comma to separate
>   OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:55]

So we tried to replace all the occurence of **\"** with single quote but the Apex complier treats **\"** as double quotes using following code:

```
jsonString.replace('\\"','\'');
```

But above didn't not work

Is there's a way to achieve what we are trying to do in Apex?

Comment: did you try to use [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) webapp ? it will generate you valid apex class and parser

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the JSON string into one of the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) deserialize methods. As the text you have posted is valid JSON, that should just work without any pre-processing being needed. (You can check that the JSON is valid by pasting into e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.)

Generally, needing to pre-process is a sign of e.g. double encoding or some other upstream mistake and it is hard to fix such a problem reliably using replace or regex logic. Best to figure out and fix the upstream problem.