# Struggling to deserialize JSON with escaped double quotes

Tags: apex, json

JSON(I am working with): JSONLinter confirms this is a valid JSON.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "params": {
                "password": "size must be between 4 and 30",
                "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Attempt 1(Using JSONParser**:

```
String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\"" } } ] }';
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(str);
while(parser.nextToken() != null){
    parser.nextToken();
}
```

Fails:

> ▸    ERROR: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('^' (code
>   94)): was  ▸    expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at input
>   location [1,99]  ▸    ERROR: Class.System.JSONParser.nextToken: line
>   94, column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1  ▸
>   AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1

**Attempt 2(JSON2Apex option)**:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Errors {
            public Params params;
    }

    public List<Errors> errors;

    public class Params {
            public String password;
            public String loginId;
    }

}

String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\"" } } ] }';
JSON2Apex obj = (JSON2Apex)JSON.deserialize(str, JSON2Apex.class);
```

Fails:

> ▸    ERROR: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('^' (code
>   94)): was  ▸    expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1,
>   column:99]  ▸    ERROR: Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column
>   1  ▸    AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock: line 2,
>   column 1

**Attempt 3(deserializeUntyped)**:

```
String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\"" } } ] }';
Map<String,Object> jsonObj = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
```

Fails:

> ▸    ERROR: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('^' (code
>   94)): was  ▸    expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1,
>   column:99]  ▸    ERROR: Class.System.JSON.deserializeUntyped: line 11,
>   column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock:
>   line 2, column 1

**Attempt 4(replace the problem causing double quote in JSON)**:

```
String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\"" } } ] }';
Map<String,Object> jsonObj = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(str.replaceAll('\"', '\\"'));
```

Still fails:

> ▸    ERROR: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('^' (code
>   94)): was  ▸    expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1,
>   column:99]  ▸    ERROR: Class.System.JSON.deserializeUntyped: line 11,
>   column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1  ▸    AnonymousBlock:
>   line 2, column 1

I have looked into the below similar questions but still don't see any solution:

1. [JSON and escaped double quote](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28105/json-and-escaped-double-quote)
2. [Replace double quotes with single quote in a JSON string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233068/replace-double-quotes-with-single-quote-in-a-json-string)

Comment: The answer on [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28105/json-and-escaped-double-quote) appears to me to be the correct one here. You are failing to escape a backslash in an Apex string literal - before you get into the JSON mechanics.

Comment: @DavidReed I am struggling to escape as suggested in that answer. What change I need to make in my `replaceAll` ?

Comment: the problem in both attempts 2 and 3 is that you are missing a \ to *escape the backslash* in the Apex string literal holding your JSON. It's in the source code, not the logic.

Comment: @DavidReed I got what you are saying but I am failing to add that extra \ to the json string before parsing. I tried doing using `replaceAll` but it is not doing it. If you can point what is wrong with my `replaceAll` (in attempt3) that would be great.

Comment: Is temporarily encoding the offending characters an option (like URL encode)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll try to illustrate this.

This is valid JSON.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "params": {
                "password": "size must be between 4 and 30",
                "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is not:

```
String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\"" } } ] }';
```

Why? Because in Apex, backslash is an escape character in a string literal. If you want that backslash to carry through to the in-memory representation of the string (your JSON), *you must escape it in your source code*:

```
String str = '{ "errors": [ { "params": { "password": "size must be between 4 and 30", "loginId": "must match \\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\\"" } } ] }';
```

Otherwise, Apex removes it, yielding an in-memory string that is *not* valid JSON because nested quote marks are not escaped:

```
"loginId": "must match "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$""
```

You don't need to use `replaceAll()` or anything fancy to fix this (and in fact, you can't - by the time you could call `replaceAll()`, the string's already broken and has no backslashes in it).

The problem is not in your logic. It's just in how you're writing string literals in your source code.

Comment: If I don't use `replaceAll`, how can I make `\"` in json to `\\"`. I understand the problem but how can I fix it at runtime?

Comment: You don't. The deserializer will handle it for you, so long as your remote party is sending you valid JSON. This is _only_ a problem when you write JSON as an Apex string literal.

Comment: Got it. I am going to try this `JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody())` and see if it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This worked. If I may suggest, can you update your answer to say "just do json deserialize with raw json output from webservice without meddling it"(something like that :))